# Equal sign incorrectly aligns with subscript

Tags: equations, subscripts

If I type

```
\mu_\bar{x}=\mu_x
```

Then the equal sign aligns with the subscript \bar{x}. However, what I want is align the equal sign with the mu, which is the big character, on the left side.

How should I change it?

Also I want spaces surrounding the equal sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$\mu_\bar{x}=\mu_x$` I get errors ("missing { and } inserted") and I see:

[image]

Put brackets around the subscript to fix it:

```
$\mu_{\bar{x}}=\mu_x$
```

Now there are no errors and you get:

[image]